# Different outputs with LSTM in PyTorch vs Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, pytorch, lstm

I am trying to convert a Tensorflow(1.15) model to PyTorch model. Since I was getting very different loss values, I tried comparing the output of the LSTM in the forward pass for the same input. The declaration and initialization of the LSTM is given below:

**Tensorflow Code**

```
rnn_cell_video_fw = tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(
            num_units=self.options['rnn_size'],
            state_is_tuple=True, 
            initializer=tf.orthogonal_initializer()
        )

rnn_cell_video_fw = tf.contrib.rnn.DropoutWrapper(
            rnn_cell_video_fw,
            input_keep_prob=1.0 - rnn_drop,
            output_keep_prob=1.0 - rnn_drop 
        )

sequence_length = tf.expand_dims(tf.shape(video_feat_fw)[1], axis=0)
initial_state = rnn_cell_video_fw.zero_state(batch_size=batch_size, dtype=tf.float32)

rnn_outputs_fw, _ = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(
                    cell=rnn_cell_video_fw, 
                    inputs=video_feat_fw, 
                    sequence_length=sequence_length, 
                    initial_state=initial_state,
                    dtype=tf.float32
                )
```

**PyTorch code**

```
self.rnn_video_fw = nn.LSTM(self.options['video_feat_dim'], self.options['rnn_size'], dropout = self.options['rnn_drop'])

rnn_outputs_fw, _ = self.rnn_video_fw(video_feat_fw)
```

Initialization for LSTM in train.py

```
def init_weight(m):
        if type(m) in [nn.LSTM]:
            for param in m.parameters():
                    nn.init.orthogonal_(m.weight_hh_l0)
                    nn.init.orthogonal_(m.weight_ih_l0)
```

[The output for tensorflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/04iPE.png)

[The output for pytorch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eq4PQ.png)

The same is pretty much the case for every data item and my PyTorch model isn't converging. Is my suspicion of difference in output  LSTM being the reason for it correct? If so, where am I going wrong?

[Link to the paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1804.00100.pdf)

[Link to TF code](https://github.com/JaywongWang/DenseVideoCaptioning)

let me know if anything else is required.

Comment: Pytorch uses `time, batch, others` on RNN modules rather than using `batch, somthing_else` and that could be the reason

Comment: Yes, I considered that as well and changed the shape accordingly but that didn't help either :(